# How to properly delete an array of ptrs? My destructors seem to be missing the actual objects

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

For example I have a Library class that holds an array of ptrs to different collections of content.

```
ContentCollection** contents;
```

But my delete seems unable to hit the actual collections (which are trees in this case).

```
Library::~Library() {
    //Delete stored ContentCollections
    for (int i = 0; i < POTENTIALCONTENTTYPES; i++) {
        delete contents[i];
        contents[i] = NULL;
    }

    delete[] contents;
}
```

Here is the destructor from the trees just in case I made a large error:

```
ContentCollection::~ContentCollection() {
    deleteHelper(root); //Deletes Contents
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Deletes stored Contents
void ContentCollection::deleteHelper(Node* curr) {
    if (curr != NULL) {
        deleteHelper(curr->left);
        deleteHelper(curr->right);
        delete curr->data;
        curr->data = NULL;
        delete curr;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty obviously doing something wrong as nearly none of my memory is deallocated.

Comment: Why is *everything* a pointer?

Comment: If you have an array of pointers, walk the array and say: `free(ptr)`  and then after that array is walked, you could then say:  `free(array_ptr);`

Comment: @Fallenreaper, Not `free`, `delete`. `free` is for memory allocated with `malloc` (which I'm really hoping wasn't used).

Comment: While I linked `free` which is C, you can also look at:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C++)

Comment: How to *properly* delete it? Use `std::vector`, rather than juggling pointers and hoping for the best.

Comment: Why do you think your memory is not deallocated? After you free memory it doesn't have to be returned to OS immediately.

Comment: are you using inheritance somewhere ? a dtor broken chain may occur if you forget virtual in front of a dtor declaration....

Comment: @alexbuisson am in fact using inheritance. Do the abstract classes all need a virtual destructor or is it all classes involved in the inheritance?

Comment: @MilanNovaković, Every abstract base class should definitely have a virtual destructor.

Comment: The virtual-ness of a destructor is inherited. No need to declare derived destructors as virtual.

Comment: @chris I only have 2 base classe (content and actions) and they both have virtual (and also empty) destructors. They aren't declared pure virtual though.

Comment: @zch I know it's not deallocated because to check for memory leaks I'm using Linux g++ valgrind

Comment: Can we see a structure of what you're trying to destroy?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `ContentCollection**` by `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ContentCollection>>`, and you won't have to worry about `delete`s anymore.

I assume `ContentCollection` is an abstract base class? Then the `destructor` needs to be virtual. Otherwise, you can ditch one level of indirection and use a `std::vector<ContentCollection>`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using vectors because of the need to carry iterators with them. I would like to avoid going back and changing the design in all the places it would need...

ContentCollection is just a BST that I named abstractly.

Comment: @MilanNovaković, You could consider making `ContentCollection` a [multi]set. It's pretty much a BST, but a bit more efficient. I'm not sure how the iterators affect you, though. `std::vector`'s random-access iterators can be used just like pointers. In fact, they probably *are* pointers.

Comment: If you don't need use iterators, they won't cost you anything.